# Prove that $\phi_g$ is an automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group, and $g$ be an element of $G$. The function (?) is defined as follows: $\phi_g:G\to G$, $\phi_g(h)=ghg^{-1}$, for every $h\in G$.
>
> Prove that $G$ is an automorphism.

I am a high school student trying to understand a little bit of abstract algebra (I know it sounds crazy), so please help me with any mistakes.

I know I need to prove that a) $\phi_g$ is a bijection and that b) $\phi_g(ab)=\phi_g(a)\cdot\phi_g(b)$ holds. \

In order to prove that $\phi_g$ is a bijection, I need to prove that $\phi_g(a)=\phi_g(b) \implies a=b$. $\phi_g(a)=\phi_g(b) \implies gag^{-1}=gbg^{-1} \implies ..$.

On the last line, can I just say that $gg^{-1}=1$ or not?

Comment: Multiply on the left by $g^{-1}$ and on the right by $g$.

Comment: How can I preserve equality by doing that @Dustan?

Comment: What do you mean? You're doing the same thing to both sides of the equation, so the equality is preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *that* hard to show $\phi_g$ is bijective the "old-fashioned" way:

Suppose $\phi_g(a) = \phi_g(b)$, that is: $gag^{-1} = gbg^{-1}$.

Thus:

$(gag^{-1})g = (gbg^{-1})g\\ga(g^{-1}g) = gb(g^{-1}g)\\ga = gb\\g^{-1}(ga) = g^{-1}(gb)\\(g^{-1}g)a = (g^{-1}g)b\\a = b.$

So, $\phi_g$ is injective.

On the other hand, let $x \in G$. Then $\phi_g(g^{-1}xg) = g(g^{-1}xg)g^{-1} = (gg^{-1})x(gg^{-1}) = x$, so $\phi_g$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of proving it is bijective, I think it's easier to give a direct construction of its inverse. Note that $\phi_g\circ\phi_{g^{-1}}=\phi_{g^{-1}}\circ\phi_g=\text{Identity map}$. Do you have problem when proving $\phi_g(ab)=\phi_g(a)\cdot\phi_g(b)$?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I am just a beginner in abstract algebra, so I don't understand your first line. When proving the second line, I also have a problem. It is just that I don't know how to deal with the $g$ and $g^{-1}$? Is there associativity, can I just say that $gag^{-1}=a$ or not? Furthermore, how do I know that the identity in the group $G$ is $1$, so how do I know that $gg^{-1}=1$ and not another number $e$?

Comment: @CauchytheDog Well, $gag^{-1}=a$ does not always hold, but associativity and the existense of a unique identity element are just part of the axioms of groups. For my first line, do you know that a map is bijective iff it admits a inverse map?

Comment: Oh, no I remember the axioms of groups, how stupid :) Could you explain your last line? I am not aware of this definition of bijectivity.

Comment: @CauchytheDog What's your definition of bijection?